# How can multiple people use the same Windows 7 key in Virtualbox VM without having to activate?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-activation

We have a .VHD of a Windows 7 installation that was just converted from a physical machine. We copy this to our local hard drive, and then load this .VHD into Virtualbox and run the Windows 7 VM from our desktop in a window. How can I make it so that this can be used by 3 or more people at once without Windows asking for activation?(in the VM window)

Comment: Are you running the VHD on one computer or more then one? if it is more then one then it is illegal it is also illegal to run it as a VM if the license was an OEM license.

Comment: More than one. Not OEM license. This is for testing our software, not for running an install at home or anything. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Unless you have a license for each system you want to run the VM on it is illegal. You can run it for the trial period legally but after that you are going to have to buy a license for each system. You could set it up on a server and have people use Remote Desktop but licensing for that my get interesting if you have more then one core or CPU in the server.

Answer (score 5):

To legally use it this way you would need to get a license for each of the extra windows installations. After you boot the VM go to [my computer], right click, select properties.

You will get this screen:
[image]

Click on "Change product key" and enter the new, legal, non OEM key.

If you want to make this a generic setup, start a copy of your 'Master VM' and run sysprep. That will remove the old key and make windows ask for the new key at first boot.